# Is there any way to take continuously updating data from excel sheet and use that data for charting

Tags: python, excel

I have excel sheet which is feeding data continuously from stock sites.
I want that data for analysis and i want to draw chart from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas read_excel('path to file'). It will read in the most recent update from the excel sheet. Then you can make whatever plots and analysis in python with the data. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Thank you I can't save that excel aheet Every second. Will it work for that??

Comment: It isnot working because i have to save that excel sheet at every second to get data.